# grep all odt files and pipe them to odt2txt

Tags: bash, shell

I want to get all `.odt` files in some folder recursively, extract their text-content and create `.txt` files from them (named accordingly, so A.odt -> A.txt)

Problem is, I am no good with shell apart from a few tricks.

grep for this is easy: `grep -r -i --include \*.odt .`

manpage of odt2txt says, I need to specify `--output=FILE`

So for one file it would be `odt2txt A.txt --output=A.txt`

This works like a charm. But how to combine those two?

I face two problems here, normally I would chain my commands (again, shell noob) with pipes, like so

`grep -r -i --include \*.odt . | odt2txt $INPUT_FROM_GREP --output=$MISSING_NAME`

But as you can see, odt2txt wants the file name as first argument, and how to get the name, without the extension to be used by `odt2txt`?

I feel like I am not on the right track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` is used to find matching lines in files, but all you seem to want to do is find files whose names match a certain pattern. For that, one would use `find`. Also, I presume that `odt2txt` wants `A.odt` as first argument, not `A.txt`.

I would use `find` to find the files, then use its `-exec` option to execute `odt2txt`. I'd use `basename` to strip of the `.odt` extension, and then I add `.txt`. So, something like this:

```
find . -name '*.odt' -exec odt2txt {} --output=`basename {} .odt`.txt ";"
```

Note that after an `-exec`, `{}` denotes the filename, and the end of the command to execute is signalled by `";"`.

Comment: What about the path in the output filename? `basename` only delivers the file name without path.

Comment: also minor thing is that files would be called .odt.txt afterwards, not just .txt (but that doesn't really matter at all)

Comment: Also it's not recursive, but that is easily added :)

Comment: `find` is recursive.

Comment: My bad... it was sooo fast though, oO converting quite a few hundreds of (bigger) texts

Comment: But then it worked, not sure what `basename` would do wrong here. Next to each `.odt` file in each sub-dir now lays a `.txt` file, just as I wanted. May I accept or is something still wrong here?

Comment: Well in my answer I had to use `dirname`+`basename` to pass the entire path. What does `odt2txt` expect? If it expects the entire path (folders+filename, e.g. `a/b/c/file.odt`), then you need to use `dirname`+`basename` to make sure it works for all nested directories. Otherwise (if `odt2txt` does not expect a path), `basename` is the correct choice.

Answer (score 2):

Using `find` and `while`:

```
find . -name "*.odt" | while read f
do
  odt2txt "$f" --output="`dirname "$f"`/`basename -s ".odt" "$f"`.txt"
done
```

Oneliner:

```
find . -name "*.odt" | while read f; do odt2txt "$f" --output="`dirname "$f"`/`basename -s ".odt" "$f"`.txt"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
#/usr/bin/bash
for i in *.odt ; do ( if odt2txt $i| grep -i $1 ;  then echo $i; fi; ) ;done
```

```
apt install odt2txt
```

and Leave grep alone!

Answer (score 0):

Below would do :

```
function odt2txtfun
{
outfilename=${1##*/}
outfilename=${outfilename%.odt}.txt
odt2txt "$1" --output="/path/to/output/folder/${outfilename}"
}
export -f odt2txtfun
find /folder/that/contains/odt/files -name *.odt" -exec bash -c 'odt2txtfun "$1"' _ {} \;
```